# moderntimeline: \tllabelcventry prints superfluous date under the time line

Tags: moderncv, moderntimeline

The `\tllabelcventry` macro doesn't work properly, displaying additional date under the time line:
[image]

instead it should print only the manually inserted label without the automatic date as stated on page 3 of [the documentation](https://ftp.lyx.org/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderntimeline/moderntimeline.pdf):
[image]

The question is: ***how to fix it?***

I believe it worked fine just one year ago. I complied the minimal example (below) in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) and on my computer using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20` with the same result.

The minimal example:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[firstyear=2000,lastyear=2021]{moderntimeline}

\firstname{A.}
\familyname{B.}

\begin{document}

\tllabelcventry{2002}{2012}{2002-2012 label}{Test}{test}{test}{}{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete the macro `\tl@endlabel` in the following line of the definition of command `\tllabelcventry`:

```
node [tl@endyear] {\tl@endlabel}
```

With the following MWE (see the code change marked with `<=======`)

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\usepackage[firstyear=2000,lastyear=2021]{moderntimeline}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tllabelcventry}[9][color1]{%
  \tl@formatendyear{#3}
  \tl@formatstartyear{#2}
  \tl@splitlabels{#4}
  \cventry{\tikz[baseline=0pt]{
    \tl@tlcvbar
    \fill [#1] (0,0)
      ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
      node [tl@startyear] {\tl@startlabel}
      rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt)
      node [tl@endyear] {} % <========================\tl@endlabel
      (\hintscolumnwidth,0pt) ;
    \ifissince
      \newdimen\fullcolorwidth
      \pgfmathsetlength\fullcolorwidth{\tl@startfraction*(1+(1-\tl@startfraction)*\tl@nsfrac)*\hintscolumnwidth}
      \shade [left color=#1,right color=#1]
        (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
        rectangle (\fullcolorwidth,\tl@width);
      \shade [left color=#1] (\fullcolorwidth,0)
        rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
    \else
      \fill [#1] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
        rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
    \fi
    }
  }
  {#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}%
}
\makeatother

\name{A.}{B.}

\begin{document}

\tllabelcventry{2002}{2012}{2002-2012 label}{Test a}{test b}{test c}{}{test e}

\end{document}
```

you get the following wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]